# In Kotlin (Android), is there a practical difference in referencing an interface as an object vs an override function?

Tags: android, kotlin, interface

So say I have an interface thus:

```
interface A {
    fun foo()
}

class SomeClass() {
    var interfaceA: A? = null
...
}
```

In my activity, I can use the interface like:

```
class someActivity : AppCompatActivity, A {
...

    private fun someFun() {
        val someClass = SomeClass()
        someClass.interfaceA = this
    }

    override fun foo() {
        do something
    }

}
```

Or I can do this:

```
class someActivity : AppCompatActivity {
...

    private fun someFun() {
        val someClass = SomeClass()
        someClass.interfaceA = object : A {
            override fun foo() {
                do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But what are the pros & cons of each way? Is there a technical reason why one should be used over the other, or does it just come down to personal preference?

I've used both methods & they seem to work equally as well, but I'm not sure if there are implications (bad or good) for using one over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an extensive answer to every possible scenario, just highlighting something.

When using:

```
class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity, A {
```

this means that `SomeActivity` is now definitely going to conform to whatever `A` is. Seems quite obvious, but where could this be relevant ?

In statements such as :

```
   fun foo(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
    if (activity is A) {
    //do something.
    }
}
```

and beyond that, if we weren't using activities specifically, this also becomes relevant in cases of dependency injection, etc.

in the event of

```
 private fun someFun() {
        val someClass = SomeClass()
        someClass.interfaceA = object : A {
            override fun foo() {
                do something
            }
        }
    }
```

this obviously is only relevant to your function and not to the entire object (activity, fragment etc.) so you do lose some of the advantages of it being on the entire class as it's then no longer of that specific type (which could also be seen as an advantage, depending on how you want to use it). This *might* also make unit tests a bit harder to do, as some of this logic is now private to this function.

Does it really make a difference ? I can't think of a really critical place where there's a difference that would matter, I suppose you could argue that having the interface in the function could *perhaps* be a violation of single responsibility, as that function might have more than one reason to change now, if you were to add additional methods to the interface, because that function then has to change when either a new function gets added or when another has to change, but beyond that I don't really think it matters too much.

Comment: Thanks for that @a_local_nobody. Actually you indirectly highlighted something for me when you mentioned the object declaration being only relevant to that function. In a case where I might have several functions referencing the interface, it makes sense to have the entire class conform to A, but if I'm only using it as a one-off, then using the object seems to make sense.